# Return multiple rows from plpgsql function

Tags: function, postgresql, plpgsql

I have the below function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function1() RETURNS TABLE(foo1 VARCHAR, foo2 VARCHAR) AS $$
    BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT e.col1, e.col2 FROM my_table e;
    END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It returns something like this:

```
function1
record
|--------------|
(a,b)
(c,d)
```

But I'm expecting a result analog to a query like this:

SELECT e.col1, e.col2 FROM my_table e;

```
  col1  col2
|-----|-----|
   a     b
   c     d
```

Because I want to execute the function a get the separates columns values in a java resultSet and iterate accros them. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [RETURN QUERY-Record in PostgreSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769212/return-query-record-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do

```
select * from function1();
```